# Alert Bar section within WP loop is displaying even though there are no posts

Tags: php, categories, loop

I'm having an issue with a stubborn template-part that wants to display on my site even when, as far as I can tell, it should not.

This section is supposed to display an alert bar at the top of the page whenever there is a post or event (a CPT) with the Alert or Notification category associate with it. I did a query_posts for those categories to see if they were associated with anything and then wrote an if-statement to only display the section if something existed.

I've checked the CMS and there is nothing with either category. Below is my code. If someone could point out my error or explain why this isn't working I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

```
<?php
query_posts( array(
    'cat'       =>  array( 23, 31 ) )
);

if( have_posts ) :
?>

<section id="alert-bar" class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

            <?php

                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                //ADVANCED CUSTOM FIELDS VARIABLES
                $event_thumb        =   get_field( 'event_thumb' );
                $alert_excerpt      =   get_field( 'alert_excerpt' );
            ?>

            <article class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 alert-image-wrapper">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $event_thumb['url']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- .col-xs-3 .col-md-offset-1 .col-md-2 .alert-image-wrapper -->

                <div class="col-xs-9 alert-text-wrapper">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <p><small><?php echo $alert_excerpt; ?></small></p>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- .col-xs-9 .alert-text-wrapper -->
            </article>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

            </div> <!-- .col-xs-12 -->
        </div> <!-- .row -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</section> <!-- #alert-bar -->


<?php endif; ?>
```

I have some styles including padding and a background-color applied to the section tag which is why I wrapped the whole thing in the if-statement.

Comment: I should mention the website's url is http://www.healthyeatingadventure.org and the alert bar appears just below the main navigation at the top of the home page. It appears as a green stripe above the jumbotron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying the main query, since you didn't set a custom one, with [new WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).
Hence, yes there are posts, just not the ones you think.

Try this:

```
 <?php

    $args = array(
        'category__in'=> array( 23, 31 )
    ); 
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Start the loop for your custom query
    if($loop->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <section id="alert-bar" class="clearfix">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                        <?php while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        //ADVANCED CUSTOM FIELDS VARIABLES
                         $event_thumb        =   get_field( 'event_thumb' );
                         $alert_excerpt      =   get_field( 'alert_excerpt' );

                        <article class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 alert-image-wrapper">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $event_thumb['url']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                </a>
                            </div> <!-- .col-xs-3 .col-md-offset-1 .col-md-2 .alert-image-wrapper -->

                            <div class="col-xs-9 alert-text-wrapper">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                    <p><small><?php echo $alert_excerpt; ?></small></p>
                                </a>
                            </div> <!-- .col-xs-9 .alert-text-wrapper -->
                        </article>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    </div> <!-- .col-xs-12 -->
                </div> <!-- .row -->
            </div> <!-- .container -->
        </section> <!-- #alert-bar -->

    <?php endif; wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know better than that but I just couldn't see it.

Comment: No worries, it happens!